# how to store flappy bird game's score into sql database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pygame

I am a beginner in pygame(using python idle)and made a simple game of [Flappy Bird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flappy_Bird) as my school project. It needs to be connected with SQL database in some way and I m storing the scores in them along with the player's name. But after finishing a round of the game and entering the above info, it doesn't restart after calling the required function(the GUI hangs) and keeps on asking to enter the player's name(on the idle). Also, the info isn't getting stored in the SQL database. I tried saving the scores in a text file and printed the output but there too, the same problem is occurring. Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import random
import mysql.connector as c

# Initialising the modules in pygame
pygame.init()

SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 750))  # Setting the display

# background
BACKGROUND_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')

#  BIRD
BIRD_IMAGE = pygame.image.load('bird1.png')
bird_x = 50
bird_y = 300
bird_y_change = 0

def display_bird(x, y):
    SCREEN.blit(BIRD_IMAGE, (x, y))

# OBSTACLES
OBSTACLE_WIDTH = 70
OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = random.randint(150,450)
OBSTACLE_COLOR = (211, 253, 117)
OBSTACE_X_CHANGE = -4
obstacle_x = 500

def display_obstacle(height):
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, OBSTACLE_COLOR, (obstacle_x, 0, OBSTACLE_WIDTH, height))
    bottom_obstacle_height = 635 - height - 150
    pygame.draw.rect(SCREEN, OBSTACLE_COLOR, (obstacle_x, 635, OBSTACLE_WIDTH, -bottom_obstacle_height))

# COLLISION DETECTION
def collision_detection (obstacle_x, obstacle_height, bird_y, bottom_obstacle_height):
    if obstacle_x >= 50 and obstacle_x <= (50 + 64):
        if bird_y <= obstacle_height or bird_y >= (bottom_obstacle_height - 64):
            return True
    return False

# SCORE
score = 0
SCORE_FONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)


def sql():
    m=c.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password= "password",database="flappy 
    bird")
    my=m.cursor()
    n=input('enter your name')
    r = maximum
    my.execute("insert into table(name, score) values({},'{}')".format(n,r))
    m.commit()
    my.execute("select * from table")
    for i in my:
      print(i)

def score_display(score):
    display = SCORE_FONT.render(f"Score: {score}", True, (255,255,255))
    SCREEN.blit(display, (10, 10))

# START SCREEN
startFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)
def start():
   # displays: "press space bar to start)
    display = startFont.render(f"PRESS SPACE BAR TO START", True, (255, 255, 255))
    SCREEN.blit(display, (20, 200))
    pygame.display.update()

# GAME OVER SCREEN
# This list will hold all of the scores
score_list = [0]

game_over_font1 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 64)
game_over_font2 = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 32)

def game_over():
   # check for the maximum score
   global maximum
   maximum = max(score_list)
   #  "game over"
   display1 = game_over_font1.render(f"GAME OVER", True, (200,35,35))
   SCREEN.blit(display1, (50, 300))
   # shows your current score and your max score
   display2 = game_over_font2.render(f"SCORE: {score} MAX SCORE: {maximum}", True, 
   (255, 255, 255))
   SCREEN.blit(display2, (50, 400))
   #  If your new score is the same as the maximum then u reached a new high score
   if score == maximum:
    display3 = game_over_font2.render(f"NEW HIGH SCORE!!", True, (200,35,35))
    SCREEN.blit(display3, (80, 100))

running = True
# waiting is going to refer to our end or start screen
waiting = True
# set collision to false in the beginning so that we only see the start screen in 
the beginning
collision = False

while running:

    SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))

    # display the background image
    SCREEN.blit(BACKGROUND_IMAGE, (0, 0))

    # we will be sent into this while loop at the beginning and ending of each game
    while waiting:
        if collision:
            # If collision is True (from the second time onwards) we will see both the end screen and the start screen
            game_over()
            sql()
            start()
        
        
        
        else:
            # This refers to the first time the player is starting the game
            start()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    #  If we press the space bar we will exit out of the waiting while loop and start to play the game
                    # we will also reset some of the variables such as the score and the bird's Y position and the obstacle's starting position
                    score = 0
                    bird_y = 300
                    obstacle_x = 500
                    #  to exit out of the while loop
                    waiting = False

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                # in case we exit out make both running and waiting false
                waiting = False
                running = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            # If you press exit you exit out of the while loop and pygame quits
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                #  if you press spacebar you will move up
                bird_y_change = -6

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                # when u release space bar you will move down automatically
                bird_y_change = 3

    # moving the bird vertically
    bird_y += bird_y_change
    # setting boundaries for the birds movement
    if bird_y <= 0:
        bird_y = 0
    if bird_y >= 571:
        bird_y = 571

    # Moving the obstacle
    obstacle_x += OBSTACE_X_CHANGE

    # COLLISION
    collision = collision_detection(obstacle_x, OBSTACLE_HEIGHT, bird_y, OBSTACLE_HEIGHT 
  + 150)

    if collision:
        # if a collision does occur we are gonna add that score to our list of scores and make waiting True
        score_list.append(score)
        waiting = True

    # generating new obstacles
    if obstacle_x <= -10:
        obstacle_x = 500
        OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = random.randint(200, 400)
        score += 1
    # displaying the obstacle
    display_obstacle(OBSTACLE_HEIGHT)

    # displaying the bird
    display_bird(bird_x, bird_y)

    # display the score
    score_display(score)


    # Update the display after each iteration of the while loop
    pygame.display.update()

# Quit the program

pygame.quit()
```

Please tell me the problem and how to solve it. Thank you!

Comment: Forgot to remove the three quotes under the sql function while aking the question. Still showing the same problem.

Comment: Please look into the correct way to use parameterized queries. Then, please use some auto formatter - this will help you immensely to identify problems. Well, in addition to linters, like pylint or flake8. Then you should try debugging, especially single stepping through your code and see what differs compared to your expectations. Set a breakpoint to after a collision was detected, play, and then check your program flow ...

Answer (score 2):

The issue is you are not fully resetting the game state.  So when the new game starts, there's immediately *still* an obstacle under the player.

Perhaps make your `start()` function reset all these fields too:

```
def start():
    # displays: "press space bar to start)
    display = startFont.render(f"PRESS SPACE BAR TO START", True, (255, 255, 255))
    SCREEN.blit(display, (20, 200))
    pygame.display.update()

    # reset for new game
    score = 0
    bird_x = 50
    bird_y = 300
    bird_y_change = 0
    OBSTACLE_WIDTH = 70
    OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = random.randint(150,450)
    OBSTACLE_COLOR = (211, 253, 117)
    OBSTACE_X_CHANGE = -4
    obstacle_x = 500
```

Comment: @Ira - What output?  Please copy it into the question.

Comment: I made the changes as per ur suggestion but the output is showing the same problems which I mentioned in my question before.